# Wordpress: Change styling according to get_post_custom() field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

This is a post about Wordpress page/text styling:
Some of my posts are in Hebrew, some are in English.

If I use font `Arial` the English letters looks a bit bigger than the Hebrew letters, by `1pt` actually so I was wondering if there is a way to apply a `font-size` that is lower by 1pt only to English letters of the font.

I could think of this solution:

Use `get_post_custom()` to get a custom field I created for the English-language posts and if field `language='English'` I would echo '...addClass('english')`to the page where class`english` has a font-size that is smaller by 1pt.
This solution is quite horrible in my opinion, I believe there is a much simpler way to get this done.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is my current solution, better solutions are of course welcome :)

```
<?php
$language_field = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'language', true);
if(strcmp($language_field,'english') == 0) {
    echo '<script>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '  $(document).ready(function() {'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '      $("#main h1").css("font-size",parseInt($("#main h1").css("font-size"))-6);'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '      $("#main p").css("line-height","1.5");'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '  });'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: @Harry I've added JS and jQuery tags to my question because first, I am talking about a jQuery function and second, because there might be a jQuery solution for this problem. As you can see I am not new to Stackoverflow and I know how to ask a question here, why would I want to mislead people to help me? Isn't that kind of beating the point of asking for help? If I'm not mistaken you tried to edit my original post and I rejected it and gave you this exact reason. You're acting like you know how Stackoverflow works so why are you suggesting a solution without actually explaining what is it?

Comment: Yeah, i'm currently looking for a jQuery font modifier function to get a better solution implemented with his.

Comment: I tried to edit your question, since doing it with JS or jQuery is way more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: Please provide a link to your website/page. I believe this is matter of `CSS`, not JS, nor jQuery or even wordpress.

Comment: @Trix please explain.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a category called `english`, which you choose for every post that's in English? Then you could check the page if it has the category, and if it does, change the font size.

Code example:

```
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'english' )) {
    echo('<style> .classname {font-size: *1px less than Hebrew*;} </style>');
}
?>
```

This should function as you want and you don't need to add custom posts, and add classes through Javascript or jQuery.

You can apply the category `English` through bulk-edit on the Wordpress dashboard, so you don't have to go into each page seperately.

More information about `in_category` can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category).

Comment: Well, now that i'm trying to implement this solution a thought crossed my mind: "What if I change font-size for the entire post? or for the entire website for that matter", I'd rather use a font modifier, that would be a preferable solution. :)

Comment: Sadly, I don't have an idea currently how to do it for pages, I'll get back on that.

Comment: It's alright, i'll just use custom fields, I've posted my solution... thanks for trying though.